# Is GeoJSON an OGC format

Tags: geojson, gml, ogc

I am using geometries in a JavaScript page and it is best to use JSON objects rather than GML which is XML based. I heard of GeoJSON, but is it an OGC open format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) is not an OGC standard:

> IETF Geographic JSON Working Group
>
> The Internet Engineering Task Force, in conjunction with the original specification authors, has formed the Geographic JSON WG to standardize the format. Work continues on GitHub at https://github.com/geojson/draft-geojson.

Answer (score 3):

OGC Standards are listed on the [OGC Standards page](http://www.opengeospatial.org/docs/is).

[image]

As you will see GeoJSON is not amongst them.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2023, GeoJSON is specified in [OGC API - Features - Part 1: Core](https://docs.ogc.org/is/17-069r3/17-069r3.html#_requirements_class_geojson). So although it is not an OGC standard by itself, it can be used to fulfill [OGC API standards](https://www.ogc.org/standard/ogcapi-features/).

Quoting the document:

> GeoJSON is a commonly used format that is simple to understand and well supported by tools and software libraries. Since most Web developers are comfortable with using a JSON-based format supporting GeoJSON is recommended, if the feature data can be represented in GeoJSON for the intended use.

In laymen terms, if you have any interest in serving out geospatial data via APIs, you should consider GeoJSON as a standard.